# How to update product position according to the sku in specific category programmatically

Tags: product, position

We have set the products position according to the sku in excel work sheet.
for example:
sku-1 | 1 , sku-2 | 2
.....
because we have thounsands of product in a specific sku, so we hope we can do this programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it:

1. with Magento API, here you can see the full documentation -
   http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalog_category.updateProduct.html
2. like Magento update it, you can see
   `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category.php` ->
   `protected function _saveCategoryProducts` and more specifically
   this:

   ```
   /**
    * Update product positions in category
    */
   if (!empty($update)) {
       foreach ($update as $productId => $position) {
           $where = array(
               'category_id = ?'=> (int)$id,
               'product_id = ?' => (int)$productId
           );
           $bind  = array('position' => (int)$position);
           $adapter->update($this->_categoryProductTable, $bind, $where);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: thank you michael. but in your scripts, where should we put the array?